# Question about VirtualQueryEx() lpAdress variable

Tags: winapi, virtual-memory, virtualquery

I am building a Memory Scanner to find malware strings in a process.
Btw, when I was searching about the VirtualQueryEx dll, I saw that people starts its variable lpAdress ( which is supposed to be the Base Address of the process) with a NULL/0 value

```
    LPVOID lpAdress = 0
```

and in each loop they increase the adress value by the size of the page they just read, so that way they go to the next page and can map all process virtual memory

```
    lpAdress += mbi.RegionSize    # mbi is a variable with MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION structure
```

So, is lpAdress the value of memory considering 0 as a start of the own process virtual memory and you dont need to get the actual base adress of the process in memory ? Sorry if my question looks dumb, but the MSDN documentation is confusing me.

Comment: Also have a look at [Virtual Address Space (Memory Management)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/virtual-address-space).

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualqueryex) seems unambiguously clear: *"`lpAddress`: A pointer to the base address of the region of pages to be queried."* If you care about all memory it seems reasonable to start scanning at the lowest possible address: 0. I don't know what *"the Base Address of the process"* is supposed to mean.

Comment: It's because I was thinking about the Base Address considering the Virtual Address of User-Space at all, so I was wondering that maybe if  you start at Address 0 you could end up scanning up the memory address of other processes too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process has it's own virtual address space that starts at 0. The various executable files (.exe / .dll / whatever) are loaded either at addresses specified in the file or more recently at random addresses for security purposes.

A process can easily have mapped memory regions at addresses lower than where the process executable is loaded. For this reason, if you want to examine a process' entire memory space you need to start at 0.

Comment: Thanks, Now It's clear to me !